# How to make a Swift String enum available in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, interop

I have this enum with `String` values, which will be used to tell an API method that logs to a server what kind of serverity a message has. I'm using Swift 1.2, so enums can be mapped to Objective-C

```
@objc enum LogSeverity : String {
    case Debug = "DEBUG"
    case Info = "INFO"
    case Warn = "WARN"
    case Error = "ERROR"
}
```

I get the error

> @objc enum raw type String is not an integer type

I haven't managed to find anywhere which says that only integers can be translated to Objective-C from Swift. Is this the case? If so, does anyone have any best-practice suggestion on how to make something like this available in Objective-C?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From the [Xcode 6.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016994-CH4-SW26) (emphasis added):

> Swift Language Enhancements
>
> ...
>   Swift enums can now be exported to Objective-C using the @objc
>   attribute. @objc enums **must declare an integer raw type**, and cannot be
>   generic or use associated values. Because Objective-C enums are not
>   namespaced, enum cases are imported into Objective-C as the
>   concatenation of the enum name and case name.

Comment: Page cannot be found on link

Answer (score 102):

One of the solutions is to use the `RawRepresentable` protocol.

It's not ideal to have to write the init and rawValue methods but that allows you to use this enum as usual in both Swift and Objective-C.

```swift
@objc public enum LogSeverity: Int, RawRepresentable {
    case debug
    case info
    case warn
    case error

    public typealias RawValue = String

    public var rawValue: RawValue {
        switch self {
            case .debug:
                return "DEBUG"
            case .info:
                return "INFO"
            case .warn:
                return "WARN"
            case .error:
                return "ERROR"
        }
    }

    public init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
        switch rawValue {
            case "DEBUG":
                self = .debug
            case "INFO":
                self = .info
            case "WARN":
                self = .warn
            case "ERROR":
                self = .error
            default:
                return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this approach. To make it perfect, one may avoid some code duplication by defining a dictionary of type `[LogSeverity: String]` and then the `rawValue` and `init?` methods can be defined by a single line.

Comment: property define in swift as
> public var webViewType : WebViewType?
is not found when i try to set it in OBJC class
> webViewController.webViewType = WebViewType.TermsOfUse

Comment: @Remy Cilia does it work in latest swift 4.1? I don't see any related symbols except typealias Swift_Enum in ProductModule-Swift.h generated header.

Comment: @Gobe can you share the example of how to write the rawValue and init? methods in a single line, please?

Comment: @DanielSanchez if you have an enum of type `LogSeverity` which is raw representable by `String`s, and you define once a dictionary of type `[LogSeverity: String]`, then the rawValue is simply `myDictionary[self]` and the init is `self = myDictionary.first(where: { $0.value == rawValue })`

Comment: What if we have associated values in enum? What is the best approach to make it available at Objective C?

Comment: I am getting error `Type 'LogSeverity.Constants' has no member 'routes'`

Comment: It seems a nice answer, but I'm getting strange bad_access crashes after trying this out.

Comment: @JafarKhoshtabiat `switch` is the keyword, not `swift`

Comment: @VladimirsMatusevics I fixed it and requested for edit, tnx for correction

Comment: I'm confused a little: after generating `LogSeverity` enum into swift.h header file, how to access the `rawValue` by enum case in objc code? There is not enum method concept in objc side, right?

Comment: @Itachi, any solution found?

Comment: rawValue isn't accessible in objc.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a solution that works.

```
@objc public enum ConnectivityStatus: Int {
    case Wifi
    case Mobile
    case Ethernet
    case Off

    func name() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Wifi: return "wifi"
        case .Mobile: return "mobile"
        case .Ethernet: return "ethernet"
        case .Off: return "off"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And how would the `name()` function be called in Objective-C?

Comment: @StephenPaul Something like ConnectivityStatusWifi. If you type that in you should see Xcode try to autocomplete.

Comment: @David but you cannot call `name()` in objc

Comment: I think you should make declare the function as public

Comment: @Chuck even public function will not expose the method.

Comment: @David I got enum `public enum TrackingValue {

 case constant(String)
 case customVariable(name: String)
 case defaultVariable(DefaultVariable)
    
    public enum DefaultVariable {
  case advertisingId
  case advertisingTrackingEnabled
  case appVersion
  case connectionType
  case interfaceOrientation
  case isFirstEventAfterAppUpdate
  case requestQueueSize
        case adClearId
 }
}` what will be best way to make it to be seen as ObjC enum? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't know why this answer got up voted, this is not accessible from Obj-C

Comment: Yes i also can also not call from objc

Answer (score 14):

Here is work around if you really want to achieve the goal. However, you can access the enum values in objects that Objective C accepts, not as actual enum values.

```
enum LogSeverity : String {

    case Debug = "DEBUG"
    case Info = "INFO"
    case Warn = "WARN"
    case Error = "ERROR"

    private func string() -> String {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}

@objc
class LogSeverityBridge: NSObject {

    class func Debug() -> NSString {
        return LogSeverity.Debug.string()
    }

    class func Info() -> NSString {
        return LogSeverity.Info.string()
    }

    class func Warn() -> NSString {
        return LogSeverity.Warn.string()
    }

    class func Error() -> NSString {
        return LogSeverity.Error.string()
    }
}
```

To call :

```
NSString *debugRawValue = [LogSeverityBridge Debug]
```

Comment: The problem I see with this is that you can't have `variables` of type LogSeverity, but otherwise OK.

Comment: This worked for me with some minor alterations.
`@objcMembers
public class LogSeverityBridge: NSObject {

    static func debug() -> String {
        return TravelerProtectionLevel.premium.rawValue
    }`

Answer (score 9):

If you don't mind to define the values in (Objective) C, you can use the `NS_TYPED_ENUM` macro to import constants in Swift.

For example:

**.h file**

```
typedef NSString *const ProgrammingLanguage NS_TYPED_ENUM;

FOUNDATION_EXPORT ProgrammingLanguage ProgrammingLanguageSwift;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT ProgrammingLanguage ProgrammingLanguageObjectiveC;
```

**.m file**

```
ProgrammingLanguage ProgrammingLanguageSwift = @"Swift";
ProgrammingLanguage ProgrammingLanguageObjectiveC = @"ObjectiveC";
```

In Swift, this is imported as a `struct` as such:

```
struct ProgrammingLanguage: RawRepresentable, Equatable, Hashable {
    typealias RawValue = String

    init(rawValue: RawValue)
    var rawValue: RawValue { get }
    
    static var swift: ProgrammingLanguage { get }
    static var objectiveC: ProgrammingLanguage { get }
}
```

Although the type is not bridged as an `enum`, it feels very similar to one when using it in Swift code.

You can read more about this technique in [Grouping Related Objective-C Constants](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/grouping-related-objective-c-constants)

Comment: This is exactly the approach I was looking for!

Comment: Of all the solutions I like this one the best, using it in a big mixed Objective-C and Swift project.

Comment: I use NS_TYPED_EXTENSIBLE_ENUM to be able to add more cases over time. Is there a way to make extensions done in Swift available to Objective-C? Marking them with @objc does not work since the extended type is the bridged struct and not an Objective-C type like NSString.

Answer (score 5):

Code for Xcode 8, using the fact that `Int` works but other methods aren't exposed to Objective-C. This is pretty horrible as it stands...

```
class EnumSupport : NSObject {
    class func textFor(logSeverity severity: LogSeverity) -> String {
        return severity.text()
    }
}

@objc public enum LogSeverity: Int {
    case Debug
    case Info
    case Warn
    case Error

    func text() -> String {
        switch self {
            case .Debug: return "debug"
            case .Info: return "info"
            case .Warn: return "warn"
            case .Error: return "error"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is my use case:

- I avoid hard-coded Strings whenever I can, so that I get compile warnings when I change something
- I have a fixed list of String values coming from a back end, which can also be nil

Here's my solution that involves no hard-coded Strings at all, supports missing values, and can be used elegantly in both Swift and Obj-C:

```
@objc enum InventoryItemType: Int {
    private enum StringInventoryItemType: String {
        case vial
        case syringe
        case crystalloid
        case bloodProduct
        case supplies
    }

    case vial
    case syringe
    case crystalloid
    case bloodProduct
    case supplies
    case unknown

    static func fromString(_ string: String?) -> InventoryItemType {
        guard let string = string else {
            return .unknown
        }
        guard let stringType = StringInventoryItemType(rawValue: string) else {
            return .unknown
        }
        switch stringType {
        case .vial:
            return .vial
        case .syringe:
            return .syringe
        case .crystalloid:
            return .crystalloid
        case .bloodProduct:
            return .bloodProduct
        case .supplies:
            return .supplies
        }
    }

    var stringValue: String? {
        switch self {
        case .vial:
            return StringInventoryItemType.vial.rawValue
        case .syringe:
            return StringInventoryItemType.syringe.rawValue
        case .crystalloid:
            return StringInventoryItemType.crystalloid.rawValue
        case .bloodProduct:
            return StringInventoryItemType.bloodProduct.rawValue
        case .supplies:
            return StringInventoryItemType.supplies.rawValue
        case .unknown:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use `[InventoryItemType  fromString:]` from objective-c: it gives the error "Receiver type 'InventoryItemType' is not an Objective-C class"

Comment: That's because in Objective-C InventoryItemType will be of type Int or NSInteger, it's not a class.

Comment: Hi @ChrisGarrett I got enum like:  `public enum TrackingValue { case constant(String) case customVariable(name: String) case defaultVariable(DefaultVariable) public enum DefaultVariable { case advertisingId case advertisingTrackingEnabled case appVersion case connectionType case interfaceOrientation case isFirstEventAfterAppUpdate case requestQueueSize case adClearId } }` what will be best way to make it to be seen as ObjC enum? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @agirault you can wrap it in another class, e.g. ```class InventoryItemTypeParser: NSObject
{
    @objc static func fromString(_ string: String?) -> InventoryItemType
    {
        return InventoryItemType.fromString(string)
    }
}```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with. In my case, this enum was in the context providing info for a specific class, `ServiceProvider`.

```
class ServiceProvider {
    @objc enum FieldName : Int {
        case CITY
        case LATITUDE
        case LONGITUDE
        case NAME
        case GRADE
        case POSTAL_CODE
        case STATE
        case REVIEW_COUNT
        case COORDINATES

        var string: String {
            return ServiceProvider.FieldNameToString(self)
        }
    }

    class func FieldNameToString(fieldName:FieldName) -> String {
        switch fieldName {
        case .CITY:         return "city"
        case .LATITUDE:     return "latitude"
        case .LONGITUDE:    return "longitude"
        case .NAME:         return "name"
        case .GRADE:        return "overallGrade"
        case .POSTAL_CODE:  return "postalCode"
        case .STATE:        return "state"
        case .REVIEW_COUNT: return "reviewCount"
        case .COORDINATES:  return "coordinates"
        }
    }
}
```

From Swift, you can use `.string` on an enum (similar to `.rawValue`).
From Objective-C, you can use `[ServiceProvider FieldNameToString:enumValue];`

Answer (score 1):

You can create an private `Inner` enum. The implementation is a bit repeatable, but clear and easy. 1 line `rawValue`, 2 lines `init`, which always look the same. The `Inner` has a method returning the "outer" equivalent, and vice-versa.

Has the added benefit that you can directly map the enum case to a `String`, unlike other answers here.

Please feel welcome to build on this answer if you know how to solve the repeatability problem with templates, I don't have time to mingle with it right now.

```
@objc enum MyEnum: NSInteger, RawRepresentable, Equatable {
    case
    option1,
    option2,
    option3

    // MARK: RawRepresentable

    var rawValue: String {
        return toInner().rawValue
    }

    init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let value = Inner(rawValue: rawValue)?.toOuter() else { return nil }
        self = value
    }

    // MARK: Obj-C support

    private func toInner() -> Inner {
        switch self {
        case .option1: return .option1
        case .option3: return .option3
        case .option2: return .option2
        }
    }

    private enum Inner: String {
        case
        option1 = "option_1",
        option2 = "option_2",
        option3 = "option_3"

        func toOuter() -> MyEnum {
            switch self {
            case .option1: return .option1
            case .option3: return .option3
            case .option2: return .option2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @Remi 's answer crashes in some situations as I had this:

[My error's screesshot](https://ibb.co/Xs9Shnv). so I post my edition for @Remi 's answer:

```swift
@objc public enum LogSeverity: Int, RawRepresentable {
    case debug
    case info
    case warn
    case error

    public typealias RawValue = String

    public var rawValue: RawValue {
        switch self {
            case .debug:
                return "DEBUG"
            case .info:
                return "INFO"
            case .warn:
                return "WARN"
            case .error:
                return "ERROR"
        }
    }

    public init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
        switch rawValue {
            case "DEBUG":
                self = .debug
            case "INFO":
                self = .info
            case "WARN":
                self = .warn
            case "ERROR":
                self = .error
            default:
                return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to create this enum from Objc, when I try [LogSeverity rawValue:] it doesn't find initializer.

Comment: How can I access the string value from objective c?