# can not use Swift class with enum in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, enums

I have a Swift class that contains below `enum`:

```
    @objc public enum AlertStyle : Int {
    case Success,Error,Warning,None
    case CustomImag(imageFile:String)
}
```

I do the bridging and other integration phases for using swift classes in Objective-C, but when I build the app, compiler shows below error:

> `<unknown>:0: error: cannot assign value of type '(imageFile: String) -> AlertStyle' to type 'AlertStyle'`

How can I fix it?

Comment: `@objc enum` cannot use associated values, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/30480399/1187415.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enum with associated values can not be represented in Obj-C. If you don't need your enum to be available from objc-c you can remove @objc declaration. In other case you need to redesign your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't use associated values in Objective C.