# Access swift enums in obj C

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, namespaces, swift-extensions

I have created an extension for UIColor in swift to add custom colors. The colors I have grouped together in their own namespace for which I have used enums with no cases. Here is the class:

```
extension UIColor {
    public enum FirstGroup {
        static var salmonColor: UIColor {
            return UIColor(red: 255.0 / 255.0, green: 102.0 / 255.0, blue: 102.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }

    public enum SecondGroup {
        static var strawberryColor: UIColor {
            return UIColor(red: 255.0 / 255.0, green: 0.0 / 255.0, blue: 128.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to call this in my swift class like `UIColor.FirstGroup.salmonColor`

Now, I would like to use this extension in my Objective-C classes too. How can I do that?

Comment: Note that you can use only Int-based enums in Objective-C

Comment: OK, even if I change the enums to Int how do I access them in objC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480338/how-to-make-a-swift-string-enum-available-in-objective-c.

Comment: Is it a full extension's code? Why don't you have some items inside your enums, only a static var?

Comment: @RomanPodymov It is just an extension to add custom colors. The enums are just to create namespace.

Comment: @MartinR I did look at that question. I was wondering if there is a different way than to create a wrapper class for enums as I don't have any cases in these enums.