# iOS (Swift): Encoding/Decoding Enums

Tags: ios, swift, enums, encode

I have some subclass of `NSObject` that defines a string representable `Enum` within in at follows:

```
class SomeClass: NSObject {

    enum Direction: String {
        case north = "North"
        case south = "South"
    }

    public var direction: Direction

    init(direction: Direction) {
        self.direction = direction
        super.init()
    }

}
```

I want to allow this class to be encoded and decoded, so I use the following:

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(direction, forKey: #keyPath(direction))
}

public convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init(direction: aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: #keyPath(direction)) as! Direction)
}
```

However, I get the following error **Argument of '#keyPath' refers to non-'@objc' property 'direction'** and when I change the definition of `direction` to

```
@objc public var direction: Direction
```

I get the error **Property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C**.

What's the best way to avoid this error, please?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

The comments explain the problem. This answers in this link suggest how to accomplish using a `String` raw representable.

[How to make a Swift String enum available in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480338/how-to-make-a-swift-string-enum-available-in-objective-c)

Comment: Try mark your `enum Direction` with `@objc`

Comment: @Tj3n Thanks ... I now get the following **'@objc' enum raw type 'String' is not an integer type**

Comment: In objc there's no enum with String, you have to use Int enum and another function/computed variable to convert it to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `rawValue` support that `String` based enums (and not only) have:

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(direction.rawValue, forKey: "direction")
}

public convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    guard let direction = Direction(rawValue: aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "direction") else {
        // direction was not encoded, we assume an encoding error
        return nil
    }
    self.init(direction: direction)
}
```