# Export swift enum in constantsToExport

Tags: swift, react-native

In my Swift native module for react-native I am trying to export to javascript a Swift enum:

```
@objc(InterfaceOrientationManager)
class InterfaceOrientationManager: NSObject {

  enum InterfaceOrientation: String {
    case landscapeRight
    case landscapeLeft
    case portrait
    case portraitUpsideDown
  }

  @objc
  static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  @objc
  func constantsToExport() -> [String: Any]! {
    return [
      "InterfaceOrientation": InterfaceOrientation
    ]
  }
```

However this isn't working I get the error "Expected member name or constructor call after type name". A screenshot is at bottom.

Is there any way to accomplish this? I was hoping to avoid doing a dictionary:

```
 let InterfaceOrientation: [String: String] = [
    "landscapeRight": "landscapeRight",
    "landscapeLeft": "landscapeLeft",
    "portrait": "portrait",
    "portraitUpsideDown": "portraitUpsideDown"
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/30480399/1187415: “@objc enums must declare an **integer raw type**”

Comment: And you probably want an enum *value* in the dictionary (e.g. InterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight), not the enum *type.*

Comment: Thanks @MartinR - so it seems the only way to export an enum with values as strings is to make it a dict?

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary from enum like this:

```
enum InterfaceOrientation: CaseIterable {
    case landscapeRight, landscapeLeft, portrait, portraitUpsideDown
}

var interfaceDictionary: [InterfaceOrientation: String] = [:]
for orientation in InterfaceOrientation.allCases {
    interfaceDictionary[orientation] = "\(orientation)"
}
```