# Parameter can not be represented in Objective C

Tags: swift, objective-c

I have a singleton class and a function that use one of its shared properties. I am getting this error:

"Method can not be marked as @objc because the type of the parameter 2 can not be represented in Objective-C".

My singleton class:

```
public class MessageManager {
    public static var shared = MessageManager()
    private init () {}
    
    public enum messageFlag: String {  // this is the enum causing the error when used 
        case sensitive
    }
    
}
```

The error is happening when i use the enum from singleton:

```
@objc func checkMessage (_sender: UIBarButtonItem? , messageId: String? = nil , flag: MessageManager.messageFlag ) {
    
}
```

I have seen other people's solutions like the use of NSObject in class but still not working. Any fix for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38490781/6576315

Comment: Do you need the enum to be a string based one? If not, you can convert it to an Int-based one, which will allow you to decorate it with `@objc`, making it available to Objective-C.

Comment: @Cristik   yes  i need the enum to be a string based on and not int based

Answer (score 2):

The `enum` is the problem. As suggested by @Cristik, you need to declare your enum as `@obj` as well, and in order to do that it needs to be an integer type.

Comment: the issue i need the enum to be string based and not int based

Comment: Yeah... no. You can't.  Objective-C enums are **only** integer types. That' all the language understands. For Objective-C/Swift interoperability you have to limit yourself to the types that Objective-C understands.