# How do I access a Swift String enum in Objective-C?

Tags: swift, objective-c, string, enums

I've got the  following swift autogen model, that i can't change

```
@objcMembers public class Device: NSObject, Codable { 

public enum Auth: String, Codable {
        case enabled = "ENABLED"
        case supported = "SUPPORTED"
        case notSupported = "NOT_SUPPORTED"
        case bypassed = "BYPASSED"
    }

public var auth: Auth
public var brand: String

}
```

I'm trying to access the enum property in my Objective-C class like this
`self.isAuthEnabled = ([Device.auth.rawValue isEqualToString:@"ENABLED"]);`

but I keep getting this error, Property 'auth' not found on object of type 'Device' even though I have access to the brand property, I can't access the enum

Comment: Only enums with integer raw values are exposed to Objective C. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38490781/5133585) still works?

Comment: That may work but I can't change the Device class

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that part of the question. I think you are kind of stuck then. You need to write a Swift wrapper of the enum that can be exposed to ObjC.

Comment: Objective C enums just don’t support this. You’ll want to make a wrapper API that you expose in place of the enum

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/grouping-related-objective-c-constants

Comment: You need declare that enum as `struct Auth: RawRepresentable, Equatable, Hashable`

Comment: @Cy-4AH The linked documentation describes how to expose ObjC types to Swift. The OP is looking for a way to do the opposite.